# Golang DeReference pointer passed to a method as an interface{}

Tags: go, pointers

Example:

```
import (
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   var v = ""
   fmt.Println(isEmptyString(&v))
}

func isEmptyString(val interface{}) bool {
   // lets say we know it is string and don't need to check
   // how to dereference val into string value so we can do value == "" ????

}
```

Normal deRef * doesn't work, tried to play with reflect package.. no luck

Comment: Please write error you get and the expectation you have as result in description of question

Comment: Take a look at my comment value == ""

Comment: You should show us what you have tried. You should also read the language specification. You should also not try something this advanced until you have a basic grasp of the language. StackOverflow is not your personal, unpaid, code writing service.

Comment: Type assertions are explained in the Tour of Go.

Comment: @Kurtis Rader I can understand your "negativity" to some extent, but what do you want me to "show us what you have tried" ? I mentioned that I tried simple deRef * and reflection, which anyway not the way I feel this problem should be solved and it doesn't make sense to post here bunch of wrong code ...  As you mentioned this something advanced .... I've been building API using go for 2+ years and didn't know about it.. That's not the primary programming language I use, so I clearly have some knowledge gaps... I pretty sure many Go programmers will not be able to tell the answer right away.

Comment: On top of that I didn't ask to write a func code I specifically asked how to de ref, which pretty much syntax question  Do you feel like providing answer *val.(*string)  is the same as implementing code for me ?

Comment: @Volker you can see in my comment below that I knew about type assertions, I just didn't know that I can deRef that the way the second answer shows

Comment: @4reeman, If you've been writing Go for two years you should know that the `*` prefix is how to deref a pointer; just like in C. And, yes, your question essentially asked for someone to fill in the body of your `isEmptyString` function; i.e., write code for you rather than help you understand why the solution(s) you tried do not work.

Comment: @Kurtis Rader You can browse documentation o tutorials for days to figure out... while if you know it will take a min to write, I think that's exactly the purpose of stack overflow.. I personally want to apologize to you that I made you feel bad, the answers bellow made my life a bit easier .. that's unacceptable !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you knows it is string and don't need to check, you can something like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var v = ""
    fmt.Println(isEmptyString(&v))
}

func isEmptyString(val interface{}) bool {
    return *val.(*string) == ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code you need is something like this :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var v = ""
    fmt.Println(isEmptyString(&v))
}

func isEmptyString(val interface{}) (bool, error) {
    switch v := val.(type) {
    case *string:
        str := *v
        if str == "" {

            return true, nil

        }
        return false, nil
    default:
        return false, fmt.Errorf("the value is not string pointer")
    }
}
```

Comment: Marked other answer as it is specifically answer my question, but this one is also interesting. I used type switch in order to determine that param is a *string, but didn't know you can just do  str := *v inside that block.